# Do date ranges in Rails include the border dates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, range

I want to query a date range in Rails:

```
User.where(:created_at => Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now.end_of_day)

Time.now.beginning_if_day is at 00:00:00
Time.now.end_of_day is at: 23.59.59
```

Does my range include those two border times, or does is use `<` and `>`?

Answer (score 3):

Opening up the good console answers all your questions.

With `..` calls a `BETWEEN` statement in the db

```
User.where(created_at: Time.zone.today.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.today.end_of_day).to_sql

# SELECT "users".* 
# FROM "users" 
# WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2017-06-06 00:00:00' AND '2017-06-06 23:59:59.999999')
```

With `...` it calls the `>=` `<` magic.

```
User.where(created_at: Time.zone.today.beginning_of_day...Time.zone.today.end_of_day).to_sql

# SELECT "users".* 
# FROM "users" 
# WHERE ("users"."created_at" >= '2017-06-06 00:00:00' AND 
#        "users"."created_at" < '2017-06-06 23:59:59.999999')
```

Rails 5.1 includes a nice little helper called [`all_day`](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/04/24/rails-5-1-has-introduced-date-all_day-helper.html) which makes this possible. It issues the same statement as with `..`

```
Users.where(created_at: Time.zone.today.all_day).to_sql
```

---

**Note:**

If you're really paranoid and have a super important life-saving app going on, `Time.zone.today` might actually change in the milliseconds from calling `beginning_of_day` and `end_of_day`, so you can do this then.

```
today = Time.zone.today
Users.where(created_at: today.beginning_of_day..today.end_of_day)
```